# Windows 8 Release Preview - missing cd/dvd drives

Tags: windows, windows-8-preview

What is the fix to get cd/dvd drives working with `Windows 8` release preview build 8400? I open my computer and cd/dvd is not visible.

Comment: Have you tried Device Manager and Disk Management Console (diskmgmt.msc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this answer while googling around, I just tested it and it works for me.

1. Run Command Prompt as an Administrator. Type cmd in Windows 8 Metro UI and press cltr+shift+enter
2. Type following and press enter

reg.exe add "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\atapi\Controller0" /f /v EnumDevice1 /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000001

3. Reboot the system
4. Verify if the problem has been resolved

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your "optical" (CD/DVD) drive or maybe just it's power has become disconnected.

Then again, maybe your BIOS settings are now ignoring certain drives or possibly even entire drive controllers. Reboot and check your BIOS settings to be sure. Or you could just check your Disk Management service (diskmgmt.msc) to see if anything is there.

Of course, if you're optical drive connects via a USB port then you may need other drivers such as chipset drivers. Don't rely on Device Manager either, particularly since it may not even show a problem if that's the case.

Hopefully, something I said helps. It's a little hard to guess since you really didn't provide much info - like if it's a laptop/desktop or how the drive is connected, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You must install Microsoft Media Center to get you DVD drive back online. I know in the Window 8 Nomenclature it says that Windows 8 Pro will support your media palyers, but that is not entirely true. If you have the base Windows 8 you must upgrade it to Windows 8 Pro to allow the installation of the Microsoft Media Center which will operate your DVD. Pretty evil don’t you think. The Media center can be purchased from Microsoft for an additional $10.00, but it ti free until January 31, 2013. Simply go to Windows 8 website, type in Media Center and follow the instructions there. It will give you a program key and installation instructions. Once installed you still will not see the drive listed in “computer” until you use it. The it will mysteriously appear and will operate normally. Now tell me this was not an intentional “glitch” form our friends in Microsoft! Good Luck! 
Avata30